# Having a hard time reading a text from png file using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

[image]

I'm having a hard time extracting the text `CHUBB` from this image above. I tried several image preprocessing techniques and `pytesseract` to extract them without success.

My Output: `\x0c`

Expected output: 'CHUBB'

Any help would be appreciated

My attempt:

````
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('image1_1.png')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

thresh1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 

                                          cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 199, 5)

cv2.imshow('Adaptive Mean', thresh1)

# De-allocate any associated memory usage   

if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:  

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
# Adding custom options
custom_config = r' --psm 3'
pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1, config=custom_config)```
````

Comment: Try otsu thresholding rather than adaptive thresholding.

Comment: I did tried it to no success:

Comment: cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + 

                                            cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

Comment: `cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`

Comment: Still does not extract the text with cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

Comment: What does your otsu threshold image look like? Please show it. Have you tried adding some white padding at the top above the letters so that they do not touch the top. Perhaps that is an issue? See cv2.copyMakeBorder() to add padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the text CHUBB is too large for the picture.
If we decrease the size a little bit or paste it into a larger canvas, then pytesseract will work fine

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.png')  # load image
new_img = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400), color = 'white')  # create a larger canvas
new_img.paste(im=img, box=(100,100), mask=img)  # paste original CHUBB in the large image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, lang='eng', config='--psm 12')  # OCR
print(text)  # CHUBB
```

FYI

```
for i in range(1,14):
    try:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, lang='eng',config=f"--psm {i}")  # OCR
        print('psm',i, text)
    except:
        pass
```

Yield

```
psm 1 CHUBB

psm 3 CHUBB

psm 4 CHUBB

psm 5 0
u
J
I
U

psm 6 CHUBB

psm 7 CHUBB

psm 8 7

psm 9 CHUBB

psm 10 CHUBB

psm 11 CHUBB

psm 12 CHUBB

psm 13 7
```